# Error:[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers vuex (nuxt.js)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I've already searched what causes this error message to appear but could not really get my head around it in my code. I'm using Nuxt.js with Vuex. I just can't see where am i modifying the store without mutation. Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong ? This error message appears when i pick some date from the date picker component. This solution works as intended, it's just the error message that bugs me and i dont really want to solve it by turning off the strict mode for store.

Component.vue

```
<template>
  <v-col class="chart">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-title>Daily beta trend</v-card-title>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="4">
          <b-form-group label="From" class="ml-3">
            <b-form-datepicker id="datepicker-from" v-model="chartDataFrom" class="mb-2" />
          </b-form-group>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="4">
          <b-form-group label="To">
            <b-form-datepicker id="datepicker-to" v-model="chartDataTo" class="mb-2" />
          </b-form-group>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="4">
          <b-form-group label="OS Version" class="mr-3">
            <b-form-select v-model="selectedOS" :options="OSVersions">
              <template #first>
                <b-form-select-option :value="null" disabled>
                  -- Please select OS version --
                </b-form-select-option>
              </template>
            </b-form-select>
          </b-form-group>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-skeleton-loader
        v-if="$fetchState.pending"
        class="mx-auto"
        max-width="300"
        type="card"
      />
      <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">
        An error occurred :(
      </p>
      <div v-else>
        <Chart :data="chartData" />
      </div>
    </v-card>
  </v-col>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from '~/components/Trends/Charts/Chart'
export default {
  name: 'BetaTrend',
  components: {
    Chart
  },
  async fetch () {
    await this.$store.dispatch('beta_trend/getChartData')
  },
  fetchOnServer: false,
  computed: {
    chartData: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.beta_trend.chartData
      },
      set (data) {
        this.$store.commit('beta_trend/SET_CHART_DATA', data)
      }
    },
    chartDataFrom: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.beta_trend.from
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$store.commit('beta_trend/SET_FROM', value)
        this.$fetch()
      }
    },
    chartDataTo: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.beta_trend.to
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$store.commit('beta_trend/SET_TO', value)
        this.$fetch()
      }
    },
    OSVersions: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.beta_trend.os
      }
    },
    selectedOS: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.beta_trend.selectedOs
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$store.commit('beta_trend/SET_SELECTED_OS', value)
        this.$fetch()
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

the store is defined like this:

```
export const state = () => ({
  chartData: [],
  from: null,
  to: null,
  os: [
    'All',
    '1803',
    '19042'
  ],
  selectedOs: null
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_CHART_DATA (state, data) {
    state.chartData = data
  },
  SET_FROM (state, from) {
    state.from = from
  },
  SET_TO (state, to) {
    state.to = to
  },
  SET_SELECTED_OS (state, os) {
    state.selectedOs = os
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async getChartData ({ commit, state }) {
    const data = await this.$axios.$get('api/frontend/trend/XXX', {
      params: {
        from: state.from,
        to: state.to,
        os: state.selectedOs
      }
    })
    commit('SET_CHART_DATA', data)
    if (state.from === null) {
      commit('SET_FROM', data.dates[0])
    }
    if (state.to === null) {
      commit('SET_TO', data.dates[data.dates.length - 1])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this issue by using Lodash's [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) method on the `get()` of my `computed` option. I do have the state that is deep copied, this way it prevents any mutation of the actual object, and can therefore be modified by the `set()` in the same way.

The only needed thing is

```js
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash-es'

export default {
[...]

chartData: {
  get () {
    return cloneDeep(this.$store.state.beta_trend.chartData)
  },
  [...]
},
```

PS: also worth mentioning that `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` is not recommended: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-clone-javascript-object/#wrong-solutions

Comment: Thank you !! I've just found similar solution with JSON.parse method but i used it in Chart component as computed property that makes a copy of passed prop. Works the same but your solution is more elegant.