# Getting mutation error in Nuxt JS while binding form with state

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuex

I am trying to bind my form's fields with my vuex store in Nuxt JS. It works fine with normal text fields with `get()` `set()` in `computed`. But having trouble in customizing getting and setting manually. I am trying to push objects to an array in a specific format from my template to store and also keep the binding among them. Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container setting-form-area-business">
    <b-form-group v-for="(input, index) in phoneNumbers" :key="`phoneInput-${index}`">
      <label>Mobile Number {{index+1}}*</label>
      <b-input-group>
        <b-form-input v-model="input.phone" @input="updateStore" class="custom-form-input-business">
        </b-form-input>
        <b-input-group-append v-show="phoneNumbers.length > 1">
          <b-button class="mobile-number-remove-btn" @click="removeField(index, phoneNumbers)"></b-button>
        </b-input-group-append>

      </b-input-group>

    </b-form-group>

    <b-form-group>

      <b-button class="jh-btn2" @click="addField">Add More Mobile Number</b-button>

    </b-form-group>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: [
      'visited'
    ],

    data() {
      return {
        phoneNumbers: this.$store.state.business.formvalue.mobileNumber.length ? this.$store.state.business.formvalue
          .mobileNumber : [{
            phone: ""
          }],


      }
    },
    computed: {
      mobilenumbers() {
        return this.$store.state.business.formvalue.mobileNumber
      },

    },
    methods: {

      addField() {
        this.phoneNumbers.push({
          value: ""
        });

      },
      removeField(index, fieldType) {

        fieldType.splice(index, 1);
        console.log('fieldType', fieldType);
        this.emitErrorStatus();
      },
      updateStore() {
        this.$store.commit('business/setformmobileNumber', {
          mobileNumber: this.phoneNumbers
        })
      }
    },
  }

</script>
```

this was working fine when I was in vue, but coming to nuxt, it is giving me error

> [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told by the error, you should not mutate the state. There are several ways to handle this one. A quick search here could give you a lot of answers.

This is mine (using Lodash's `cloneDeep`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/66262659/8816585